# How can i convert Future<User> to User in my class?

Tags: flutter, dart

What i am trying to do is i am fetching profile from fetchUser.But i don't know any other way that i can pull http data other than string.

```
class FollowingUserModel {
  final String id;
  final String author;
  User profile;
  final String profileid;

  FollowingUserModel({this.id, this.profileid, this.author, this.profile}) {  profile = fetchUser() as User; }

  Future<User> fetchUser() async{
    final response = await http.get("$SERVER_IP/api/users/$profileid/?format=json");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
      return User.fromJSON(responseJson);}}

  factory  FollowingUserModel.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap) {
    return  FollowingUserModel(
      id: jsonMap['id'] as String,
      author:  jsonMap['author'] as String,
      profileid: jsonMap['profile'] as String,
);}}
```

Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: not really.I don't know what to do as it has too much explanation there.It would be better if you break it down as an answer. @nvoigt

Comment: Well, the point of duplicates is that we do not want to have a single, hand-tailored answer for each variant of the same problem, as it makes it hard to find a solution, since each answer only applies to the exact question asked. Since your question is very broad, I don't know how to narrow down an answer. Do you have anything *specific* that you have problems with? Do you get compiler errors, runtime errors?

Comment: I explained it up there,i will explain it again. I want to fetch my User from my class,but i don't know how to return it as a regular User. I want to assign the fetchUser() value to "profile"  correctly,thats what i mean.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. The two answers you got are correct, to wait for a Future to finish and get it's result, you need to use the `await` keyword as shown. If you want to know *why* you have to do that, you can follow my link above. If you have a problem with doing what the answers says, you need to either edit your question to be more specific about the problem you have with it, or ask a follow up question if you think it's too much for a single question.

Comment: I get what you mean.The thing is that i tried both of them,but they still give errors for me. I call my functions from FollowingUserModel class,not inside state or so because it would be too hard for me instead of this one.Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Well, why don't you post what you tried and post the errors you got? How are we supposed to help you with errors you don't post here?

Comment: check the comments that i left in the answers please...

Comment: I did. I still have no idea what your code looks like. This is my final comment on this issue: *post your code and the errors that you have*. Preferably as a [mcve]. Otherwise we won't be able to help you. We cannot guess what you did wrong in your code if you don't show us your code.

Comment: question has the code look up please

Comment: say , you want to convert Future<User> to User in the same class ?

Comment: yes.That is my problem

Comment: You have not yet understood a core concept of dart, **asynchronous programming**. That is not a bad thing, nobody was born with an understanding of that concept, we all had to learn it at some point. You can read the link I provided, or you can read the links the answers provided, or you can read a good book or other teaching material of your choice. But you have to understand that there are no easy answers here. This is not a misplaced comma we can fix. It won't work the way you try it. You have to take the time and read up on the concept, understand it, and *then* find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create an **asynchronous function** .

If you have `Future<User>`, to convert it to `User`, you need to add `await`; and to use `await`, you need to add `async`:

```
Future<void> test() async {
  User user = await fetchUser();
}
```

You can learn more about asynchronous function **[here](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)**

Comment: The operator '<' isn't defined for the type 'Type'.

Comment: i have to get the user out of the Future async function to be able to assign it to "profile". Inside,it works

Answer (score 0):

From where you are calling do this,

```
User user = await followingUserModel.fetchUser();
```

`Future<User>` means it will return an User object by asynchronously(in future), so make the call with `await`, then your code will wait till it get the return.

Comment: I need to call it inside the class model that i am using.Can you instruct me more please?

Comment: where are you calling fetchUser() function?
Then why are you fetching data inside a model class?
separate the responsibility of the classes.